# Removing certain set of value within Python request text

Tags: python, python-requests

I got this chunk from a response text after calling an API. How do I remove only the set with '"id": 23732 along with its other key:values ,' from the string?

```
{
  "jobs": [
    {
      "id": 23732,
      "status": "done",
      "name": "TESTRBZ7664"
    },
    {
      "id": 23730,
      "status": "done",
      "name": "RBY5434"
    }
  ]
}
```

TQ

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! in the future, please make sure to include examples of what you've already tried so far and where exactly you're stuck so we can give you more precise answers (and you'll even learn more along the way! :) )

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the string to a json using `json.loads()` or `response.json()`
2. See the following code

```
In [4]: d
Out[4]:
{'jobs': [{'id': 23732, 'status': 'done', 'name': 'TESTRBZ7664'},
  {'id': 23730, 'status': 'done', 'name': 'RBY5434'}]}

In [5]: [i for i in d["jobs"] if i["id"] != 23732]
Out[5]: [{'id': 23730, 'status': 'done', 'name': 'RBY5434'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dict you posted is called `original_dict`, you could build a new dict using a list comprehension:

```py
new_data = {
    "jobs": [x for x in original_dict if x["id"] != 23732]
}
```

This doesn't strictly remove the entry from your original dict, it rather creates a new dict that doesn't contain the unwanted entry.
Read more about list comprehensions here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp